# How to count the number of characters in files using RDD.wholeTextFiles?

Tags: apache-spark

I created an RDD as follows:

```
val manylines = sc.wholeTextFiles("c:\\spark\\*.txt")
scala> manylines
res23: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)] = d:\spark\*.txt
MapPartitionsRDD[1] at wholeTextFiles at <console>:24
```

How to count how many characters are in each line in each file?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process the content use `mapValues` instead of `map`:

```
manylines.mapValues(_.length)
```

But if you want to process lines you'll have to go deeper, for example

```
manylines.flatMapValues(_.split("\n")).
  mapValues(_.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in displaying the total number characters in the file -  you can map each line to its length and then use the implicit conversion into DoubleRDDFunctions to call `sum()`:

```
manylines.map{ case(key, value) => value }.map(_.length).sum
```